# Docker stack deploy - turn off autorecreate after system restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose

how to turn off autorecreate docker stack after system restart?

It is possible to do it?

Case - i click turn off computer, waiting, turn it on again, but my containers are recreated instead of start again. My database is recreated (that is main problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not keeping any `data` in container. Put your data in a  [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) so that it is persistent on reboot. Being married to a single container instance isn't really docker philosophy.

Comment: i give up too fast, i found information about volumes like minute ago, it works! Thank you very much for fast answer

Comment: @Razikus great. happy to help!